# Solve $\sqrt I = (x,y,z)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I want to find all the ideals $I$ of $k[x,y,z]$ such that $\sqrt I = (x,y,z)$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field.

I know that for such an ideal, we can find integers $a,b,c \geq 1$ such that $(x^a, y^b, z^c) \subset I$. I guess that by taking $a,b,c$ minimal, we actually have an equality, but how do I prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have equality: $I=(x^2,xy,xz,y^2,yz,z^2)$ is not of
the form $(x^a,y^b,z^c)$. One does have $\sqrt I=(x,y,z)$ iff
$(x,y,z)\supseteq I\supseteq (x,y,z)^m$ for some $m\in\Bbb N$.